# HAProxy - balance according to url_parameter

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, url-routing

I have 2 different tomcat servers: T1 , T2

My clients that refer to my load balancer are providing the url parameter called "gender" (0 - for Male users , 1 - for Female users). only the url parameter is different between a male and a female call.

I would like to balance with haproxy to T1, T2 according to the gender parameter. (Males will be redirected to T1, Females to T2)

How can i Achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Well, you don't say what version of HAProxy you're using, but assuming it's 1.5.x, you could use the `urlp` fetch method something like so:

```
acl IsMale   urlp(gender) 0
acl IsFemale urlp(gender) 1
use_backend T1 if IsMale
use_backend T2 if IsFemale
```

There's more details on the `urlp` fetch [here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.6-url_param).